# How to access objects in R workspace by position?

Tags: r

I'm certain the answer is goingt to be very simple.  Assume I have a number of data frames in my workspace, from a function that reads in a large number of files.

```
for(i in 1:10) {
    df <- data.frame(matrix(1, nrow=10, ncol=20))
    assign(paste0("df", i), df)
    rm(list=c("df", "i"))
    }
```

How can I access the data frame (or an object) by the position in the workspace as opposed to its name?

For example, assume I wanted to make a copy of the first object in my workspace.  I can identify the object by `ls()[1]`.  But, how could I extend that to actually access the data frame.  Of course, `temp <- ls()[1]` doesn't work.  Any help in pointing out the obvious would be helpful!

Comment: You could try `get(ls()[1])`

Comment: @RichardScriven That was the obvious answer I was looking for.  Feel free to add as answer, so I can give you credit.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using `assign()`. Creating a bunch of variables like this is almost always a bad idea because they are hard to work with. You should probably be consolidating your data in a list. For example

```
df <- lapply(1:10, function(i) {
    data.frame(matrix(1, nrow=10, ncol=20))
}
```

then you can access the data frames with

```
df[[1]]
df[[2]]
```

etc. But if you really wanted to extract elements by the index in the `ls()` result, you can change the variable name to a value with `get()`, ie `get(ls()[1])`. But i would strongly recommend against this since the order returned by `ls()` isn't guaranteed to have any meaning or even necessarily be the same each time it's called.

Comment: That makes sense.  My use of assign() was really just for a reproducible example.  I am reading in a large number of files, all of the same structure but different names.  For convenience, I want to grab a specific row of one of the files, so selecting an object from the workspace was my intention.

Comment: I see no reason you wouldn't use a list for that scenario as well. If you're new to R and you're using `get` and `assign` then changes are you aren't doing things the "R-like" way.

Comment: Point taken.  I will give a shot at re-writing the code to stay closer to R conventions.  Yes, still new to R...